# Format uitextfield while typing

Tags: ios, objective-c

Can anybody help with formatting UITextfield to be in decimal format.
When I enter the first digit, the result should be: "**0.01**"
When I enter the second digit, the result should be: "**0.11**"
When I enter the second digit, the result should be: "**1.11**"

I am new to Objective-C. Thanks in advance.

Comment: so... what have you tried beside asking a complete solution for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a `delegate` for your `UITextField` object. This delegate must adopt the `UITextFieldDelegateProtocol`.
The delegate should implement the method `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`. This method is called every time the user types into the text field.
In this method, you can replace the typed string with the string that you want.